# Какой указатель следует возвращать из функции в C++?

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11

Какого вида указатель лучше возвращать из функции? Сырой или все же unique/share? Сырым указателем можно инициализировать умный, но если этого не сделать, то может произойти утечка памяти.

Comment: Указатель может подразумевать *владение* указуемым ресурсом, а может подразумевать простую ссылку на ресурс *без владения* им. Вот от этого деления и зависит выбор типа указателя. А уж имеет место владение или нет - зависит от каждого конкретного случая.

Comment: Если умеете готовить сырые, то возвращайте сырые. Но, например, сырой указатель на массив с заранее неизвестным количеством элементов возвращать не стоит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on, как говорится.

Представьте себе, что вы возвращаете указатель на некоторый статический массив или на что-то еще - словом, не на память, которая должна быть удалена. Заворачивание его в интеллектуальный указатель вряд ли имеет большой смысл...

Или, скажем, вы подготовили в памяти строку и решили ее вернуть как указатель. Тогда уж имеет куда больший смысл вернуть ее как `string`.

Словом, единственно верного решения не существует и не может существовать. Всегда надо исходить из конкретной задачи, а не из абстрактных представлений :)

Но, понятно, что если речь идет о возврате динамической памяти, которую нужно не забыть удалить - то да, лучше прибегнуть к интеллектуальному указателю.